# How do you reboot Windows Server 2003 and be sure it does NOT install any updates

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-update

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you reboot Windows Server 2003 and be sure it does NOT install any updates](https://serverfault.com/questions/353906/how-do-you-reboot-windows-server-2003-and-be-sure-it-does-not-install-any-update)

We need to reboot a win 2003 standard server with the least amount of down time possible. What steps do you take to ensure no windows updates will be applied durring the reboot?

Thanks